# Will an Android phone backup include Facebook Messenger messages?

Tags: samsung, backup, facebook-messenger

I couldn’t  figure this out or find an answer, but if the Facebook Messenger app is included in an Android Phone backup, are Messenger messages stored within the app in the phone backup?

My initial assumption was no because it’s web based and would pull the newest messages/upstate them when all is running.

Thanks!

Comment: If you mean Facebook Messenger messages, no, they will not be backed up and other than some cache space, they are not even stored locally. If you are using FB Messenger for SMS messages (using it as your texting application), I don't believe so.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. How were you able to figure that out?

Comment: Install it in a different device without backup/restore... Everything is there upon login.

Comment: Does the fact that they are downloaded from the cloud upon login definitely mean the app does not back them up in the phone backup? Meaning is it an inference that they wouldn’t need to be backed up in the phone backup? I tried to check the storage sizes but I don’t know what parts of the app are backed up.

Comment: Actually, the Facebook messenger app doesn’t appear to even be in the list of apps in an android backup - do you see this as well on a Samsung?

Comment: I haven't owned a Samsung device since 2011 and likely never will again... I can't answer this question